# website player able to cut specific part of the video and save it as a new video

Tags: php, flash

i am just curious if this kind of technology for flash is available.

Can a website flash player able to cut specific part of the video and save it as a new video through php and flash.

i hope someone can give me some guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to have the flash object remember the timecode for the cut(s) and pass it back to the server where a server side video processing application would then copy the source video and make the cuts and then save it as a new file.